# SwiftUI HStack within a scroll view not showing images correctly

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode12

I have the following:

It shows just 1 image if 1 is available or if more than one image is there, it creates a `HStack` which should be `scrollable` to show all images:

```
 ScrollView {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            if userData.profileURL1 != nil {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack {
                        URLImage(URL(string: userData.profileURL)!, placeholder: Image(systemName: "circle"),
                         content:  {
                            $0.image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 33),height: 500)
                            }
                        )
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                        .padding([.leading,.trailing])
                        URLImage(URL(string: userData.profileURL1!)!, placeholder: Image(systemName: "circle"),
                         content:  {
                            $0.image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 33),height: 500)
                            }
                        )
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                        .padding([.leading,.trailing])
                        if userData.profileURL2 != nil {
                            URLImage(URL(string: userData.profileURL2!)!, placeholder: Image(systemName: "circle"),
                             content:  {
                                $0.image
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 33),height: 500)
                                }
                            )
                            .cornerRadius(12)
                            .padding([.leading,.trailing])
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                URLImage(URL(string: userData.profileURL)!, placeholder: Image(systemName: "circle"),
                 content:  {
                    $0.image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 33),height: 500)
                    }
                )
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .padding([.leading,.trailing])
            }
       }
}
```

The logic works and it displays multiple images if more than one are there, but doesn't show them correctly, the height of the images is not being applied from what I can tell:

[image]

[image]

The images are scrolling to show the other but the height is all messed up. But when only 1 image is present (else) then the image shows fine, full height and everything.

Comment: try setting frame to your placeholders inside `HStack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollView does not know height of content, you have to specify it explicitly. By your code it looks like it should be

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack {
        URLImage(URL(string: userData.profileURL)!, placeholder: Image(systemName: "circle"),
         content:  {
            $0.image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 33), height: 500)
            }
        )

      // .. other content here

    }
    .frame(height: 500)     // << here !!
```